# Willow Problems

Tags: bonsai

I started a Green Willow from a cutting 2 mo. ago. Doing fine until 2 days ago.
Getting round holes and chew marks on the leaves.   Sprayed for bugs and cut the affected leaves off.  It doesn't seem to help.  Any suggestions?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to not spray insecticides on your plants until you've positively identified the insect you're trying to kill. so that you can use the proper pesticide. Without a photo it's hard to tell, but round holes in leaves usually are caused by slugs, not insects.

Comment: Leaves with holes are generally being eaten, they are not diseased. Thus, removing them is not going to help, and will weaken the tree.